# RFECV for feature selection for imbalanced dataset

Tags: feature-selection

I'm currently new in Machine Learning and I just learned about feature selection. In my project, I have a dataset with 89% being a majority class and 11% as the minority class. Also, I have 24 features. I opted to use Recursive Feature Elimination with Cross-Validation (RFECV in the scikit-learn package) to find the optimal number of features in the dataset. I also set the 'scoring' parameter to 'f1' since I'm dealing with an imbalanced dataset. Furthermore, the estimator I used is the Random Forest classifier. After fitting the data, I had around 12 features with an f1 score of 0.94.

Is using RFECV appropriate for imbalanced datasets?

Comment: Intense study will be needed to meet your goals.  Start by studying the difference between classification and prediction, why prediction is more useful, why prediction doesn't care about imbalance, proper accuracy scoring rules, etc.  A starting point is https://fharrell.com/post/classification

Comment: I think a lot of us would say that this kind of stepwise procedure is inappropriate for balanced datasets, too. // You say that you just learned about feature selection. What did you learn about feature selection?

Comment: I learned that feature selection can be used to reduce features to reduce running time for training and testing and to avoid high dimensionality of the data